# How to change package information thru Java code?

Tags: java

In my current  Java project,  I have written a Java program that copies  some  Java  files  from  package "fr.inria.arles.pankesh.gen"  to package "fr.inria.arles.pankesh.impl".

After copying  Java  files from  package “fr.inria.arles.pankesh.gen”   to  package “fr.inria.arles.pankesh.impl” ,  my java files  are giving errors , due to  package Information change of Java file.

My question is  “Is there any way to change package  information ( thru java code, not manually) in header , when  my program copies Java files from package “fr.inria.arles.pankesh.gen”   to  package “fr.inria.arles.pankesh.impl”.

Comment: You should accept answers to some of your questions.

Comment: No, you either have to edit all the package statements or use a real IDE with refactoring capability.

Comment: @duffymo Well, Eclipse is written in Java, and its refactoring capability renames the package declaration. There is a way to do this.

Comment: Yes Jeffrey, but Eclipse parses your source code into an abstract syntax tree and builds that capability into the command that's executed when you move source between packages.  It's not trivial.

Comment: There is a way to do this, and I just described one technique.  Eclipse parses all the files into a giant `Tree`, so it only really rewrites the `Tree` of all data, and then flushs it back to disk.  And Pankesh, if you think an answer helped you, vote it up with the up arrow above the number.  If you think it really was the thing that solved your problem, accept it.  It is a common courtesy to give some credit to those who are willing to help.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, but since the OP is only interested in changing the package declaration, and since the package declaration is always the first non-comment statement in Java source, it would be fairly easy to modify it. However, modifying the imports will prove a much more challenging proposition.

Comment: Fairly easy?  Please post an answer, and show how it'd work with a modest number of .java files in the original package.  Ten should do.  I'll look forward to your response that isn't a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy java source files, you need to

1. Open the source file.
2. Open the destination file.
3. Copy everything from the source into the destination, up until you see the `package` keyword.
4. Copy the package keyword into the destination file.
5. Write the "corrrect" package location into the destination file
6. Skip over the "incorrect" package location in the source file
7. Write the remainder of the contents from the source file into the destination file.

Note that this will correctly "rebase" a file's package; but it will do nothing to "rebase" other files which might expect to find that file in the "old" package.  To fix those other files (if they exist, perhaps your project is designed to not have so many reference, or you intend to copy all the files), you need to open up each file in your project looking for the "moved" class in an `import` statement.  If you find it, you need to *not* copy the import but copy in the correct replacement.

When working with a file that doesn't really "move" but needs to be changed, the best strategy is to write a temporary file, and then to replace the original with the temporary file after the temporary file is completely written.  Like so:

```
(reading) MyClass.java
(writing) .tempMyClass.java
(done writing)
(moving)  .tempMyClass.java to MyClass.java
```

This allows you to not be constrained by a number of nasty items, like writing in the file past where you need to read from (which will destroy the information you need before you read it).

The packages `java.io` and the class `java.lang.String` have all the utilities to allow you to write these tools, but to go into detail would be far too long a post.  Try writing a little bit, search the web for (how do I read lines from a file with java, how do I write lines to a file with java) when you get stuck, post the code for how far you have gotten and your specific error or misunderstanding, and plenty of people will be happy to help.

If you want to do this for already-compiled files, you need to either read up a bit on the java class file format, and find the class name constant string, and alter it by a similar procedure above (except you will be writing binary bytes), or you could use a library like ASM to do the same procedure as above (but perhaps save you the mistakes you might make when doing it by hand).

Comment: This is very tedious and lengthy solution. I accept it, but it is not relevant to my context.

Comment: It is a tedious and lengthy solution; however, it is exactly relevant to your context, as it does exactly what you are asking to do.  If you can find a different way to honor the Java Language Specification without doing this, then write it up as an answer to your own question.  Now the tedious part you can do away with by writing a Java program which automates this, but you can't do _less_ work and expect the end result to compile as it won't be a valid Java project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with lots of effort,

1. parsing you Java files, and update them (it is not easy, just consider when there is `package` word in your comments or Strings).
2. And you shall update all classes refering to them (which is even harder, cause you shall change the import statements, change fully qualified class names, and add import statements to classes within same package (because they were neighbors and there were no import statements).

I recommend you to use and IDE (such as Eclipse, Netbeans or IDEA) and use its refactoring feature.